# In odoo How to Add Amount in Words / Text to Printed Invoice?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, erp, invoice

I want to print the total amount as text format in an invoice generated by using odoo.
Note that that I want to convert Indian rupee(INR) to text format.

example:

INR 1500

desired output: one thousand five hundred

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a compute field and convert the amount to words in python.... below i have provided a example:

```
num_word = fields.Char(string="Amount In Words", compute='_compute_amount_in_word')

    def _compute_amount_in_word(self):
        for rec in self:
            rec.num_word = str(rec.currency_id.amount_to_text(rec.amount_total)) + ' only'
```